# What is the passive voice of a sentence that is structured as 'past perfect' before 'simple past'

Tags: passive-voice, past-perfect, simple-past

For example, how would the sentence below be expressed in the passive voice?

> I had completed all tasks before they arrived.

Comment: All tasks had been completed before they arrived. Where is your problem?

Comment: It's not that I'm having any problem. I was just not sure how it changes in passive voice.

Comment: _All tasks had been completed by me before they arrived._

Comment: The sentence is flawed. To what does *they* refer? If it refers to tasks, how can they be completed before they arrive? If it refers to visitors, there is no context to show their relevance to tasks.